# Generalization of summation over primes

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given a prime $p$ we have that $\sum \limits_{ i =0}^{p-1} i^a \mod p$ equal $0$ if $p-1 \not\mid a$ and equals $p-1$ if $p-1|a$.

Can we generalize this result for prime-powers or primorials or any(or most of the) integers.

I know that we have to change $p-1$ to $\phi(n)$ for example or just sum over all the numbers that are coprime to $n$ or one might need to change the summand like from monic $i^a$ to something like $i^a + i^{ \phi(n)-a }$, all of this is not the important part here, what i am asking or what i want to generalize is if lets say given $n$ then there is some number call it $div_n$ such that for all integers $ 0<a<div_n$ then the summation mod $n$ is zero and when $a=div_n$ then the summation is not zero (i prefer if its $\phi(n)$ or $n-1$) ??

**Edit** I want that $div_n \geq \sqrt{n}$ for instance, this condition is to make sure that the powers of $5$ lets say for example don't follow the same pattern as $5$ it self like the summation mod $5^3$ is non-zero when $4|a$ but this is $\phi(5)$ and not $\phi(5^3)$.

Comment: It definitely extends to odd prime powers (since they have primitive roots), with $\phi(p^r)$ in place of $p-1$ and with the summation going over all coprime residue classes. Then use the Chinese remainder theorem to derive the general case from the case of prime powers (powers of $2$ are their own special case).

Comment: @CalvinLin but then for smaller value of $a  =\phi(n)$ would have non-zero summation !

Comment: @GregMartin but it will not be always zero for values less than $\phi(n)$ !

Comment: Oh no, nm, I misread your summation. Sorry.

Comment: @CalvinLin if i used $div_n = \phi(n)$ for prime-powers then it will sum for non-zero but not all the values of $a< div_n$ will have a non-zero summation, i put it in the edit after your comments

Comment: For prime powers, this is somewhat similar to Theorem 2.1 Case 1 on page 8 of https://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/obj/s4/f2/dsk2/ftp04/mq24272.pdf.  This is my Master's thesis but it was 25 years ago, so I don't remember all the details, but you may be able to reuse some of the lemmas.

Comment: @GregMartin could you please expand your comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said in a comment that

> i want that the only non-zero value mod $n$ is for some $a\ge \sqrt n$, i put it in the edit i call such special value $div_n$, also the summand dont have to be $i^a$ it can be for example $i^a+i^{2a}$.

So, I guess that the following claims may interest you.

**Claim 1** : For all $r\ge 1$ and for all $a\ge 2$,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}\bigg(i^a+i^{3a}\bigg)\equiv 0\pmod{2^r}$$

**Claim 2** : Let $r\ge 2$. If $1\le a\le 2^r$, then
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}\bigg(i^a+i^{a\left\lceil \frac{a}{2^r}\right\rceil}\bigg)\equiv 0\pmod{2^r}$$ If $a=2^{r}+1$, then $$\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}\bigg(i^a+i^{a\left\lceil \frac{a}{2^r}\right\rceil}\bigg)\not\equiv 0\pmod{2^r}$$
(So, letting $n=2^r$, we have $\color{red}{div_n=n+1}$.)

**Claim 3** : $p$ is an odd prime. For all $r\ge 1$ and for all $a\ge 1$,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p^r-1}\bigg(i^a+(p-1)i^{pa}\bigg)\equiv 0\pmod{p^r}$$

**Claim 4** : $p$ is an odd prime. Let $r\ge 1$. If $1\le a\le p^r-1$, then
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p^r-1}\bigg(i^a+(p-1)i^{pa\bigg(1+(p-2)\left\lfloor \frac{a}{p^r}\right\rfloor\bigg)}\bigg)\equiv 0\pmod{p^r}$$
If $a=p^r$, then
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p^r-1}\bigg(i^a+(p-1)i^{pa\bigg(1+(p-2)\left\lfloor \frac{a}{p^r}\right\rfloor\bigg)}\bigg)\not\equiv 0\pmod{p^r}$$
(So, letting $n=p^r$, we have $\color{red}{div_n=n}$.)

---

In the following, I'll give a sketch of proofs for the claims (the claims can be proved using [this](https://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/obj/s4/f2/dsk2/ftp04/mq24272.pdf) written in Erick Wong's comment).

Let $[n]$ be the set of integers between $1$ and $n$ (the inclusion
of $n$ does not affect any sum modulo $n$), and $[n]^*$ be the subset of $[n]$ consisting of integers relatively prime to $n$.

---

**Claim 1** : For all $r\ge 1$ and for all $a\ge 2$,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}\bigg(i^a+i^{3a}\bigg)\equiv 0\pmod{2^r}$$

*A sketch of a proof for claim 1* :

It holds for $r=1$. For $r\ge 2$,
$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}i^a&\equiv\sum_{i\in [2^r]}i^a\pmod{2^r}
\\\\&\equiv \sum_{i\in [2^r]^*}i^a\pmod{2^r}\qquad\qquad \text{(Theorem 2.2)}
\\\\&\equiv \begin{cases}0&\text{if $a$ is odd}\\ \phi(2^r)&\text{if $a$ is even}\end{cases}\pmod{2^r}\qquad\qquad\text{(Theorem 2.1)}\end{align}$$
Therefore, we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}i^a+\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}i^{3a}\equiv \begin{cases}0+0&\text{if $a$ is odd}\\ \phi(2^r)+\phi(2^r)&\text{if $a$ is even}\end{cases}\equiv 0\pmod{2^r}.\ \ \blacksquare$$

---

**Claim 2** : Let $r\ge 2$. If $1\le a\le 2^r$, then
$$\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}\bigg(i^a+i^{a\left\lceil \frac{a}{2^r}\right\rceil}\bigg)\equiv 0\pmod{2^r}$$ If $a=2^{r}+1$, then $$\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}\bigg(i^a+i^{a\left\lceil \frac{a}{2^r}\right\rceil}\bigg)\not\equiv 0\pmod{2^r}$$
(So, letting $n=2^r$, we have $div_n=n+1$.)

*A sketch of a proof for claim 2* :

For $1\le a\le 2^r$, we have $\left\lceil \frac{a}{2^r}\right\rceil=1$, so
$\text{LHS}\equiv 2\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}i^a\equiv 0\pmod{2^r}$.

For $a=2^r+1$, we have $\text{LHS}\equiv \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{2^r-1}\bigg(i^{\text{odd}}+i^{\text{even}}\bigg)\equiv \phi(2^r)\not\equiv 0\pmod{2^r}.\ \ \blacksquare$

---

**Claim 3** : $p$ is an odd prime. For all $r\ge 1$ and for all $a\ge 1$,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p^r-1}\bigg(i^a+(p-1)i^{pa}\bigg)\equiv 0\pmod{p^r}$$

*A sketch of a proof for claim 3* :

$$\begin{align}\sum_{i=0}^{p^r-1}i^a&\equiv\sum_{i\in [p^r]}i^a\pmod{p^r}
\\\\&\equiv \sum_{i\in [p^r]^*}i^a\pmod{p^r}\qquad\qquad \text{(Theorem 2.2)}
\\\\&\equiv \begin{cases}0&\text{if $p-1\not\mid a$}\\ \phi(p^r)&\text{if $p-1\mid a$}\end{cases}\pmod{p^r}\qquad\qquad\text{(Theorem 2.1)}\end{align}$$
Therefore, we have
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p^r-1}i^a+(p-1)\sum_{i=0}^{p^r-1}i^{pa}\equiv\begin{cases}0+(p-1)\times 0&\text{if $p-1\not\mid a$}\\ \phi(p^r)+(p-1)\phi(p^r)&\text{if $p-1\mid a$}\end{cases}\equiv 0\pmod{p^r}.\ \ \blacksquare$$

---

**Claim 4** : $p$ is an odd prime. Let $r\ge 1$. If $1\le a\le p^r-1$, then
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p^r-1}\bigg(i^a+(p-1)i^{pa\bigg(1+(p-2)\left\lfloor \frac{a}{p^r}\right\rfloor\bigg)}\bigg)\equiv 0\pmod{p^r}$$
If $a=p^r$, then
$$\sum_{i=0}^{p^r-1}\bigg(i^a+(p-1)i^{pa\bigg(1+(p-2)\left\lfloor \frac{a}{p^r}\right\rfloor\bigg)}\bigg)\not\equiv 0\pmod{p^r}$$
(So, letting $n=p^r$, we have $div_n=n$.)

*A sketch of a proof for claim 4* :

For $1\le a\le p^r-1$, we have $pa\bigg(1+(p-2)\left\lfloor \frac{a}{p^r}\right\rfloor\bigg)=pa$, so $\text{LHS}\equiv 0\pmod{p^r}$.

For $a=p^r$, we have $\text{LHS}\equiv \displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{p^r-1}\bigg(i^a+(p-1)i^{pa(p-1)}\bigg)\equiv (p-1)\phi(p^r)\not\equiv 0\pmod{p^r}.\ \ \blacksquare$

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to compute $S(n,a) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} i^a$ modulo $n$ for integers $n,a \geqslant 1$. First of all, as you said, $S(p,a) =_p 0$ if $p - 1|a$, $-1$ else when $p$ is prime (I didn't verify it, I assume you proved it). Now, let us try to express $S(nm,a)$ for a product $nm$ with $n,m \geqslant 2$. Using euclidean division, any integer $0 \leqslant i \leqslant nm - 1$, $i$ decomposes uniquely as $nj + r$ with $0 \leqslant r \leqslant n - 1$ and $0 \leqslant j \leqslant m - 1$ thus, modulo $n$, we have,
\begin{align*}
S(nm,a) & =_n \sum_{i = 0}^{nm - 1} i^a\\
& =_n \sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1} \sum_{j = 0}^{m - 1} (nj + r)^a\\
& =_n m\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1} r^a\\
& =_n mS(n,a)\\
& =_n nS(m,a) + mS(n,a).
\end{align*}
Similarly, modulo $m$, we have $S(nm,a) =_m nS(m,a) =_m nS(m,a) + mS(n,a)$. The chinese reminder theorem implies that modulo $nm$, $S(nm,a) =_{nm} nS(m,a) + mS(n,a)$. Notice that the factors $n$ and $m$ are important because thanks to them, if $S(n,a) =_n x$ and $S(m,a) =_m y$, then $S(nm,a) =_{nm} ny + mx$ thus it is enough to know $S(n,a)$ modulo $n$ and not modulo $nm$, same thing for $S(m,a)$. By induction on the number of prime divisors of $n$, we obtain,

**For all $n = \prod_{p \in \mathbb{P}} p^{v_p(n)}$, for all $a \geqslant 1$,**
$$
S(n,a) =_n \sum_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{n}{p^{v_p(n)}}S(p^{v_p(n)},a).
$$

Using this, it is enough to compute $S(q,a)$ for $q = p^m$ power of a prime. Using the same method than previously, we can compute that for all $p \in \mathbb{P}$, $m \geqslant 1$,
\begin{align*}
S(p^{m + 1},a) & =_{p^{m + 1}} \sum_{i = 0}^{p^{m + 1} - 1} i^a\\
& =_{p^{m + 1}} \sum_{j = 0}^{p - 1}\sum_{r = 0}^{p^m - 1} (p^mj + r)^a\\
& =_{p^{m + 1}} \sum_{j = 0}^{p - 1}\sum_{r = 0}^{p^m - 1} \sum_{k = 0}^a \binom{a}{k}p^{mk}j^kr^{a - k}\\
& =_{p^{m + 1}} \sum_{j = 0}^{p - 1}\sum_{r = 0}^{p^m - 1} \binom{a}{0}r^a + \binom{a}{1}p^mjr^{a - 1}\\
& =_{p^{m + 1}} \sum_{j = 0}^{p - 1}\sum_{r = 0}^{p^m - 1} r^a + ap^m\sum_{j = 0}^{p - 1}\sum_{r = 0}^{p^m - 1} jr^{a - 1}\\
& =_{p^{m + 1}} pS(p^m,a) + ap^mS(p,1)S(p^m,a - 1)\\
& =_{p^{m + 1}} pS(p^m,a) + \frac{ap^{m + 1}(p - 1)}{2}S(p^m,a - 1)\\
& =_{p^{m + 1}} pS(p^m,a) \textrm{ if $p$ is odd.}
\end{align*}
and when $p = 2$, $S(2^{m + 1},a) =_{2^{m + 1}} 2S(2^m,a) + a2^mS(2^m,a - 1)$ when $a \geqslant 2$ (and $S(2^m,1) =_{2^m} \frac{2^m(2^m - 1)}{2} =_{2^m} 2^{m - 1}$). Notice that once more, the factor $p$ implies that if we know perfectly $S(p^m,a)$ modulo $p^m$, we know $pS(p^m,a)$ and hence $S(p^{m + 1},a)$ modulo $p^{m + 1}$. Indeed, an immediate induction gives us that,

**For all odd prime $p$, for all $m \geqslant 1$,**
$$
S(p^m,a) =_{p^m} p^{m - 1}S(p,a) = -p^{m - 1}\mathbf{1}_{(p - 1)\mathbb{N}}(a)
$$
In the case of $p = 2$, there is a little complication but numerical observations suggest that $S(2^m,a) =_{2^m} 2^{m - 1}$ if $2|a$ or $a = 1$, $0$ else by induction. Indeed, if $m = 1$ or $m = 2$, we can easily check it by hand and for $m \geqslant 3$, assume that this result is true at rank $m - 1$. We already know that $S(2^m,1) =_{2^m} 2^{m - 1}$. Let $a \geqslant 2$ is even,
$$
S(2^m,a) =_{2^m} 2S(2^{m - 1},a) + a2^{m - 1}S(2^{m - 1},a - 1) =_{2^m} 0
$$
and if it is odd,
\begin{align*}
S(2^m,a) & =_{2^m} 2S(2^{m - 1},a) + a2^{m - 1}S(2^{m - 1},a - 1)\\
& =_{2^m} 2^{m - 1} + 2^{m - 1} \times 2^{m - 2}\delta_{a - 1,1}\\
& =_{2^m} 2^{m - 1} \textrm{ because $2m - 3 \geqslant m$ since $m \geqslant 3$.}
\end{align*}
It gives us the formula,

**For all $m \geqslant 1$,**
$$
S(2^m,a) =_{2^m} 2^{m - 1}\mathbf{1}_{2\mathbb{N} \cup \{1\}}(a)
$$
Finally, if $n \geqslant 2$, we can use the previous formulas to get that if $n$ is odd,
\begin{align*}
S(n,a) & =_n \sum_{p \in \mathbb{P}} \frac{n}{p^{v_p(n)}}S(p^{v_p(n)},a)\\
& =_n -\sum_{p \in \mathbb{P},p|n} \frac{n}{p^{v_p(n)}}p^{v_p(n) - 1}\mathbf{1}_{(p - 1)\mathbb{N}}(a)\\
& =_n -\sum_{p \in \mathbb{P},p|n,(p - 1)|a} \frac{n}{p}.
\end{align*}
Now, consider an even $n$. If $a = 1$, $S(n,1) =_n \frac{n(n + 1)}{2} =_n 0$ because $n$ is even. Consider now $a \geqslant 2$. We have,
\begin{align*}
S(n,a) & =_n 2^{v_2(n)}S\left(\frac{n}{2^{v_2(n)}},a\right) + \frac{n}{2^{v_2(n)}}S(2^{v_2(n)},a)\\
& =_n -\sum_{p \in \mathbb{P},p \geqslant 3,p|n,(p - 1)|a} \frac{n}{p} + \frac{n}{2}\mathbf{1}_{2\mathbb{N}}(a)
\end{align*}
To summurize,
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
n & a & S(n,a) \, \mathrm{mod}\, n \\
\hline\\
\textrm{Odd} & \textrm{Any integer} & \displaystyle -\sum_{\underset{p|n,(p - 1)|a}{p \in \mathbb{P}}} \frac{n}{p}\\
\hline\\
\textrm{Even} & = 1 & \displaystyle \frac{n}{2}\\\\
\hline\\
\textrm{Even} & \textrm{Odd and } > 1 & \displaystyle S(n,a) =_n -\sum_{\underset{p \geqslant 3,p|n,(p - 1)|a}{p \in \mathbb{P}}} \frac{n}{p}\\
\hline\\
\textrm{Even} & \textrm{Even and } > 1 & \displaystyle S(n,a) =_n -\sum_{\underset{p|n,(p - 1)|a}{p \in \mathbb{P}}} \frac{n}{p}\\
\hline
\end{array}
Now, to determine the couples $(n,a)$ such that $S(n,a) =_n 0$, let us begin to prove that for any non-empty finite set $S \subset \mathbb{P}$, $\sum_{p \in S} \frac{1}{p}$ is not an integer.

Indeed, let $P = \prod_{p \in S} p$ and $Q = \frac{P}{p_0} = \prod_{p \in S,p \neq p_0} p$ where $p_0 \in S$ is any element. Since all elements of $S$ are prime, $p_0\not\mid Q$ (they are even coprime) thus,
$$
P\sum_{p \in S} \frac{1}{p} = Q + \sum_{p \in S,p \neq p_0} \frac{P}{p} = Q + p_0\sum_{p \in S,p \neq p_0} \frac{Q}{p} =_{p_0} Q \neq_{p_0} 0,
$$
thus this integer is not a multiple of $p_0$ and a fortiori not a multiple of $P$. We deduce that the sum $\sum_{p \in S} \frac{1}{p}$ is never an integer which implies (still if $S$ is non empty) that $\sum_{p \in S} \frac{n}{p}$ is never a multiple of $n$.

Therefore, we can do a case disjunction to deduce from this result and the previous array of formulas that,

**For all $n \geqslant 1$, for all $a \geqslant 1$, $S(n,a) =_n 0$ if and only if one of the two following excluding conditions is fulfilled,**

$*$ $n$ is odd and for all prime number $p$ that divides $n$, $p - 1$ doesn't divide $a$.

$*$ $n$ is even, $a$ is odd and $> 1$ and for all odd prime number $p$ that divides $n$, $p - 1$ doesn't divide $a$.

You defined $\mathrm{div}_n$ to be the smallest $a$ such that $S(n,a) \neq_n 0$. We deduce from the previous point that if $n$ is odd, $\mathrm{div}_n = p_0 - 1$ where $p_0$ is the smallest prime number that divides $n$. If $n$ is prime, $\mathrm{div}_n = n - 1 > \sqrt{n}$ but if $n$ is not prime, $p_0 \leqslant \sqrt{n}$ (because $p_0$ is the smallest divisor of $n$ that is not $1$) hence $\mathrm{div}_n < \sqrt{n}$. In the case where $n$ is even, $S(n,1) =_n \frac{n}{2} \neq_n 0$ so $\mathrm{div}_n = 1 < \sqrt{n}$. Therefore, $\mathrm{div}_n > \sqrt{n}$ if and only if $n$ is an odd prime number.

Comment: It seems that your conclusion is wrong. Take $n=4$ and $a=3$.

Comment: You are right, I went too fast on the case of the powers of $2$. I edited, it should be better.

Comment: So it cant be generalized to arbitrarly large a in respect to n, thanks i will study your answer

Comment: What do you mean ? The size of $a$ with respect to $n$ doesn't matter

Comment: it does i want that the only non-zero value mod n is for some $a \geq \sqrt{n}$ , i put it in the edit i call such special value $div_n$, also the summand dont have to be $i^a$ it can be for example $i^a+i^{2a}$.

Comment: I added a few words in the end about $\mathrm{div}_n$. If you replace $i^a$ by $i^a + i^{2a}$, your sum becomes $S(n,a) + S(n,2a)$. I don't understand exactly what you want, find a summand such that $\mathrm{div}_n > \sqrt{n}$ ? Any summand ? What are the conditions on it ? If your summand is $0$, your problem is solved. Same thing with $i^{n!a + 1}$ because in this case, the $p - 1$ will never divide $n!a + 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Connection with Bernouilli numbers can be interesting. It follows from Faulhaber's formula and Von Staudt-Clausen theorem that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k^a\equiv B_a n\pmod n.$$

Example:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2519}k^{12}\equiv 2520B_{12}\equiv 2520\left(-\frac{691}{2730}\right)\equiv 2076 \pmod{2520}$$
Example: If $n=p$ and $p-1|a$ then since $B_a+\frac1p\in \Bbb Z_{(p)}$ by Von Staudt-Clausen theorem, we have
$\sum_{k=1}^{p-1} k^a\equiv pB_a\equiv -1$ modulo $p$.